# How to identify whether an item in an SVN diff is a file or a folder?

Tags: svn, post-commit

I'm writing a post-commit hook, in which I use svn diff -summarize to get a summary of what was changed. When files/folders are added or modified, I can simply get their file type in a working copy that is kept updated at all times automatically. But when a file or folder is deleted, I have no way of finding out whether an item in the svn diff -summarize was a file or a folder.

One workaround I've thought for this is to keep another working copy, updated automatically, but always kept one revision behind the other working copy. That way, if a file/folder was deleted, I could get it in the older working copy. However, I think that this is an extraordinarily inefficient way of doing this, forcing me to keep two different working copies at the same time, and I was wondering whether there is anything in SVN that'd help with this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing svn hooks of any type, if you need information about the repository or about a transaction, you want to use the `svnlook` program from a shell script, or use the svn API in the language of your choice.  Using `svnlook` is faster, as it bypasses all the svn RA (remote access) code, including the layer of authorization checks - because the scripts are being run in the context of the server, this isn't a problem.  Additionally, you don't have the additional overhead of updating a working copy that you aren't using for, well, anything other than file type information.

`svnlook` contains numerous options for investigating both revisions (for post-* hooks) and transactions (for pre-* transactions).  Of particular interest here is the `changed` option.

```
changed: usage: svnlook changed REPOS_PATH

Print the paths that were changed.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : specify revision number ARG
  -t [--transaction] ARG   : specify transaction name ARG
  --copy-info              : show details for copies
```

The changes that made up the revision or transaction are displayed, like so:

```
A   trunk/src/new-dir/
A   trunk/src/new-dir/newheader.h
A   trunk/src/new-dir/newsrc.c
U   trunk/src/existingsrc.c
```

Output from svnlook, when referencing a directory, always ends in /.  This is an easy discriminator for detection of file or directory.

However, things do get a little murkier when dealing with deletes.  If a directory is deleted, everything under the directory is also removed and this information isn't displayed in `changed`.  See here:

```
D   trunk/src/new-dir/
U   trunk/src/existingsrc.c
```

Based on the description of what you are looking at, I'm going to guess that you are looking for some form of post-commit reporting.  If so, you may want to check out [the subversion mailer post-* hook](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/mailer/).  Even if you don't want to email results, the code demonstrates how to walk through a transaction or revision for changes using the svn API.

Comment: Wow, I had never thought about that. Thank you for answering the question, even though I've already given up on this and moved to Git.

Comment: @BrunoDeBarros I can't say that I blame you.  4 months is enough time for anyone to reconsider.